# How to restore the values of Radio Btn or Combo Box for Windows Store apps in Settings Charm.?

Tags: xaml, radio-button, windows-store-apps

I finished the App and need to add Settings in settings charm page. On that  One option is to select the difficult mode (Easy, Medium, Hard).

So, I decided to use Combo Box or RadioBtn But. I don't know how to restore the values of that.(When i closed & reopened Again).

In Hands on Lab. will have explanation for Toggle btn oly. Anyone help to give solution for this. . and also comment the link for Learning XAML top to bottom.

Thanks in Advance.. ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use local app data store (local settings) to save the value. When combo box value is selected save the selected item in local settings container.

`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["Difficulty"] = SELECTED_COMBO_BOX_VALUE;`

After user has set the value and next time when user opens the setting menu read that value and display in combo box or radio button.

`var ComboboxValue = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["Difficulty"];`

Comment: Thank for your reply. I tried that Way. But, After Saving the Combo box value i don't know how to retrieve those data(By directly assigning those values shows some null reference error). 
And I also want to know How to restrict the access of the Combo Box / Radio Btn. after i enter into the game. Because, Once user entered into the game. he/she should not change the difficulty mode.

Comment: I suggest you store index of combo box rather than value. So when you retrieve the value, you can set that value to combo box easily. If you want to restrict user to not change value then you also can use local settings. Just pass true/false as string as local setting doesn't allow to store bool, may be.

Comment: I used Radio Btns. to solve that isssue. But I just want to know Combo Box and Basic Knowledge about XAML. 

Can you paste link for some good tutorials or forums links about XAML. That will be helpful for me.